# 3 columns layout 1 column with 2 rows equal spacings

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve this responsive fluid layout in CSS, so each column has the same height and width, the middle column has 2 rows and the space between columns and rows should be identical, and when resizing the spaces should maintain equal distances. Each block is an image.

seee picture:

[image]

I've tried adding percentages to each column so 1% padding between columns and 8.3% approx margin bottom on the top row of column 2, it doesn't seem very accurate nor reliable, is there a better that works from ie8+ up.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the gaps always stay the same size, or increase/decrease based on window size? You'd better post what you have so far.

Comment: could be both really

Comment: Are you looking for something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/e5yfry2o/

Comment: This [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/taL63wfs/) could be close to it, but not sure if it will work when filling with images.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Explanation in comments.

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    -webkit-columns:auto 3;
    -moz-columns:auto 3;
    columns:auto 3;
    -webkit-column-gap:10px;
    -moz-column-gap:10px;
    column-gap:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red; /* just to show container dimensions */
}
.container>div {
    background-color:grey;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box; /* in case you plan on using padding */
}
.container>div:not(:nth-child(3n+1)) { /* second and third div from every set of 4 divs */
    height:calc(50% - 5px); /* minus half of the space between the two smaller boxes */
}
.container>div:nth-child(4n+2) { /* second div from every set of 4 divs, if there's only going to be one set, you can use :nth-child(2) instead */
    margin-bottom:10px; /* this should be the same as your column gap */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT:

Here's a much simplier solution, which has better browser support:

```css
table{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

td{
    background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks nice, did you see "is there a better that works from ie8+"?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Try tables?

Comment: No need to say that, it can be helpful too.

Comment: It might. I also suggested that in the comment under the question.

Comment: but using a tables for layout?

Comment: @user1937021 If it works for what you're doing, I don't see why not. It's always a bit tricky supporting older versions of IE and you're often going to have to use tricks to achieve your goals.